# Reliable delivery of information between a browser and a locally run service using port knocking

Tags: tcp, communication, reed-solomon, websecurity

**The goal**

Allow a browser to exchange information with a service running locally. Allow the service to figure out the user (logon session in Windows) who runs the browser. Avoid, if possible, storing a TLS certificate and private key on the machine. A bonus task: provide a solution for the setup where an anti-virus software like Kaspersky or Sophos proxies all TCP connections.

**The story**

The underlying OS is Windows, but can be any modern OS. There is a daemon running in the system. In case of Windows this is a Windows service. There is a JavaScript loaded by an Internet browser from a remote server which sends data to the daemon. The daemon does not have an HTTP/HTTP server. Instead the daemon opens N ports and listens for incoming connection. The N is a low two digits number.

The JS initiates TCP connections to a selected group of ports K in the range N. In the current implementation JS attempts to load JS scripts from 127.0.0.1:port-number. The daemon accepts the connection and immediately closes it (kinda port knocking). The daemon recovers the data from the ports "knocked" by the JS.

In the current implementation the backend chooses a unique tuple of ports, for example a 3 ports combination. The tuple is a key identifying the browser session. The service collects "knocks" - the ports accessed by a specific OS process. The service queries the backend using the collected ports.

One of the goals of the solution is to avoid implementation of HTTP/HTTPS server in the service and save maintenance of a SSL certificate.

**The problem**

- The order in which JS connects to the ports is not defined. Specifically two browsers can run knocking sessions simultaneously.
- The service can fail to open some of the ports in the range N because the
  ports are busy.

The order is not critical because the server chooses a unique [combination](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Combination.html) from the range N. I need the system to tolerate missing ports. I was thinking about choosing more than one tuple and using more than one range N.

**The question**

How can I adopt [FEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction) for the problem? Does the design make sense?

Comment: See also https://github.com/larytet/port-knocking-ipc/blob/master/README.md

Comment: `Does the design make sense?` For doing what exactly? And what are the reasons you choose this way? Right now it sounds somewhat insane. ... Avoiding TLS certificates is no reason for the whole port knocking etc.etc. (and your system also has nothing TLS would give you). And I also don't see a problem where FEC can help. Filling in the missing ports? But you know port numbers are very limited, not arbitrary data?

Comment: ...In short, what you should do now is to take a step back and describe your goals, not your current way to reach them.

Comment: @deviantfan I avoid the TLS certificate because I am going to deploy the daemon on a 3rd party machines. I do not want to keep the private key for a certificate if I do not have to. This is why I thought about port knocking. Filling in the missing ports - I have figured out how to do it. I wonder if I can do it simpler. Right now I send more than one ports tuple, create all possible combinations with the ports I failed to bind. See details https://github.com/larytet/port-knocking-ipc  I agree that the design is insane.

Comment: I can not use a simple HTTP server in the daemon, because of mixed content limitations. There are not many ways to send a message from a browser to a local service. HTTP/HTTPS server is legit. I can try to  modify the browser page title, load a CPU core in a specific pattern, etc.

Comment: Here is yet another way. Set a PAC file which points to the proxy server 127.0.0.1:8080 for domain name *.mylocaladdress.com. In the browser open a page which attempts to load a JS file from my-cool-cookie.mylocaladdress.com In the service collect all HTTP CONNECT requests (only HTTP server is required), get PID of the connecting application, reject the requests with 400, send the domain name to the server.

Comment: I have added the **goal** to the question

Comment: Yet another alternative is DNS proxy running on the client machine. It will work like the PAC file approach. Another approach  is to send every SYN packet to the server two times. One SYN from the browser's socket, second  SYN from the service running on the client machine and listening to the traffic. The second SYN has the same TCP sequence number and carries meta info - user login details. Sophos will break this approach.